# Who can get UN kicked out of New York City?

Tags: united-states, united-nations, treaty, contract-law

There's a fairly large amount of people who think UN should be kicked out of New York City.

Why and whether it's a valid point of view is rather irrelevant. What I'm interested in, what would be required and based on that, who has the power to do so and would have to be on board with it to make it happen?

E.g., does the mayor of NYC have the power to do this? President of Unites States? NYC zoning board? UN General Assembly only? UN Security Council only? Majority of US Senate?

Comment: More likely, the UN will decide to move to a city or cities with a lower cost of living.

Comment: Is this meant as a legal or a political question? Legally, it’s simple – nobody can (the GA can decide to move the seat elsewhere, but you couldn’t call that “kicking out”). Politically, there are more options, since the US could in theory, e.g., block physical access (thereby gravely annoying all the other member states).

Comment: @phoog - since when do UN bigwigs concern themselves with lowering costs at the expense of less glamour/convinience/fun? :)

Comment: @chirlu The legal question would seem to come down to "which parties can renounce the UN Headquarters agreement?":  https://treaties.un.org/doc/Publication/UNTS/Volume%2011/volume-11-I-147-English.pdf

Comment: @origimbo: Yes, and the US can’t.

Comment: @chirlu Do you have a source for that? Given how little international law there actually is, normally the answer to can you renounce a treaty seems to be "yes, but it's a potential act of war". http://openscholarship.wustl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1227&context=law_lawreview might be relevant as well.

Comment: @user4012 I'm not sure, but UN agencies are in fact reducing their presence in New York in favor of other cities.  It will be a long time, if ever, before the UN leaves the city entirely, but a voluntary departure still seems more likely than an expulsion.

Comment: @origimbo: It’s [customary law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customary_international_law) that an international treaty can only be terminated unilaterally if there is a provision in the treaty that allows it. The Vienna Conventions on the Law of Treaties codify this (article 54 of each), although neither has been ratified by the US.

Comment: @phoog - "more likely" - correct. My question was on technical grounds - who is **able to**, not whether it's likely.

Comment: @chirlu blocking physical access would be a violation of the headquarters agreement.

Comment: @user4012 I understand that, which is why I commented rather than answering.  As it happens, the convention provides for its own termination if the UN decides to relocate.  I guess that would require a vote of the GA, but I don't know.  The US can obviously influence UN decisions because it is a member state of the UN.

Comment: @phoog: Yes, blocking physical access would be illegal. This doesn’t mean it can’t be done. That’s why I am asking whether it is meant as a legal question.

Comment: Nobody. NOT unless US amends the constitution.

Comment: @mootmoot perhaps you can expand that into an answer with a justification or source.

Comment: Check out USA property rights.

Comment: @phoog: Is the reduced presence really a "departure", though, or just a geographical diversification driven by the manifest disadvantages of operating from NYC (e.g. high property costs, crowding, &c), or any centralized location?

Comment: @jamesqf It's not a departure, of course, but given enough time and financial pressure it could turn into one.  It's certainly not about "geographical diversification"; it's about setting up operations centers in places where local staff are less costly and international officers do not need a cost-of-living adjustment to their salaries.  I don't imagine it would turn into a departure, certainly not in the next several decades, but still it is a plausible scenario for the UN's deciding to relocate its headquarters. The US ceasing to be willing to host the UN seems far more unlikely.

Comment: @phoog: That's really what I meant by "geographical diversification".  I mean, they could pack up and move everything to Geneva (though that's hardly a low cost of living area :-)), or they could locate different functions in different places.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The key part of the [UN headquarters agreement](https://treaties.un.org/doc/Publication/UNTS/Volume%2011/volume-11-I-147-English.pdf) is

> *Section 23* The seat of the United Nations shall not be removed from the headquarters district unless the United Nations should so decide.

So the only body that can decide to move the headquarters in the UN itself, ie the General Assembly.

The Mayor of New York certainly has no power to remove the UN. The President could make life difficult for UN diplomats, but he also doesn't have the power to move the Headquarters to another location.

Answer (score 5):

James' answer covers the legalities pretty succinctly.

Technically, however, the POTUS *could* kick the UN Headquarters out of New York,  by "simply" unilaterally withdrawing the US from any and all United Nations memberships and treaties -- at which point the US would no longer be bound by the UNHQ agreement and could tell them to piss off.

Of course, the diplomatic, political and economic cost of a move like that would be catastrophic, but if he really wanted to, he could.

What would be more likely to happen in practice would be that the US would formally ask the UN to move their headquarters elsewhere, and the UN would probably answer "Sure, just as soon as we agree on another country/city to host the HQ and finish building it" which would probably take quite a while.

Comment: On unilaterally withdrawing, sort of - [Goldwater v. Carter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldwater_v._Carter) suggests that if the President decides to withdraw from a treaty, SCOTUS may be willing to hear the constitutionality if the Senate passes a resolution dissenting to the withdrawal.